# Storing images in AWS ECR using namespaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

AWS claims to support namespacing rules on repos but I don’t follow how you're supposed to set them up.  According to the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Repositories.html):

> Repository names can support namespaces, which you can use to group
> similar repositories. For example if there are several teams using the
> same registry, Team A could use the team-a namespace while Team B uses
> the team-b namespace. Each team could have their own image called
> web-app, but because they are each prefaced with the team namespace,
> the two images can be used simultaneously without interference. Team
> A's image would be called team-a/web-app, while Team B's image would
> be called team-b/web-app.

So we created a repo in our registry at `<registry ID>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/mycompany/myproj`

Based on this, I would then expect to be able to store multiple images in this `myproj` namespace such as:

`<registry ID>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/mycompany/myproj/imageone:latest`

`<registry ID>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/mycompany/myproj/imagetwo:latest`

However, when I try to push one of these images, it tells me the repository `mycompany/myproj/imageone` does not exist.  I don't know why it's thinking that `imageone` is part of my repository name and not my image name:tag.  Am I doing something wrong here with how my repository is named or how I'm naming/tagging my images?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ECR doesn't support "namespaces" as a hierarchical grouping concept. While ECR has a flat structure, it's common to use slashes within repository names to organise repositories.

In your example, you would create two repositories with names:

1. `mycompany/myproj/imageone`
2. `mycompany/myproj/imagetwo`

You could then use this naming convention to write identity-based policies, e.g. IAM group `myproj` could be granted permissions to resource `arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:123456789012:repository/mycompany/myproj/*`. Other than that, there's nothing special about using the common prefix and ECR considers them two repositories that happen to be named similarly.

Comment: Gotcha.  That makes sense.  The IAM permissions are where the benefit comes in.  Thank you.

Comment: I think this response deserves to be marked as the answer :)

Comment: Unless AWS has changed its policies, you cannot actually limit IAM access to individual repos for certain actions and must specify asterisk, defeating that benefit of this approach.